# How to set multiple values of properties inside an object in C#?

Tags: c#, class, object, properties

Please tell me how to add multiple properties inside an single object.
like- if there is a class having 5 variables defined with get and set.
I want to add like 2 values for each variable through a single object of that class like

```
class Info{
    int count{get , set,};
    string name{get , set,};
    string Dept {get , set,};
    string Address {get , set,};
    long contact {get , set,};
  info obj =new Info();
  /* Now after this I want to take 2 rows like 
    in first row I want to set it's values through a single object 
      Count=1,name="Robert",Dept="Computer",Address="India",Contact=434343
    in row 2nd row
      Count=1,name="Robbin",Dept="Electronic",Address="Colombo",Contact=54545                                    
  */  
}
```

/// Now please explain me how to set like above two rows values inside one object..  ///

Comment: I think you want to take a look at arrays and lists?

Comment: Java or C#? Don't tag both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is inline object initialization: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-initialize-objects-by-using-an-object-initializer

You can write it on a single line but the code would look better if you break it into multiple lines:

```
Info infoObj = new Info
{
    Count = 1,
    Name = "Robert",
    Dept = "Computer",
    Address = "India",
    Contact = 434343
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you mean is initializing a class with set properties, look at Peter Sandor's answer.
if you're looking to declare a class with a set of fields that'll be filled with values upon initialization without giving them values (aka. default values), then this might help:

```
class Info 
{
  public int count = 5;
  pubic string name = "Robert"
}
```

Please note that these are fields and not properties though, if you'd like to do the same with properties instead of fields, i'd suggest doing this with propfull:

```
private int count = 5;

public int Count
{
    get { return count; }
    set { count = value; }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating an instance of the Info class, make a List of Info:

```
List<Info> aSingleObj = new List<Info>();
```

Now you can add as many things to the single object:

```
aSingleObj.add(new Info { Count = 1, name = "Robert", Dept = "Computer", Address = "India", contact = "434343" });

aSingleObj.add(new Info { Count = 1, name = "Robbin", Dept = "Electronic", Address = "Colombo", contact = "54545" });
```

To distinguish between them, and print the output, do:

```
Console.WriteLine($"First row: Count = {aSingleObj[0].Count}, Name = {aSingleObj[0].name}, Department: {aSingleObj[0].Dept}, Address = {aSingleObj[0].Address}, Contact = {aSingleObj[0].contact}");
```

and for second row:

```
Console.WriteLine($"Second row: Count = {aSingleObj[1].Count}, Name = {aSingleObj[1].name}, Department: {aSingleObj[1].Dept}, Address = {aSingleObj[1].Address}, Contact = {aSingleObj[1].contact}");
```